# Magento2 newsletter not sending the success mail

Tags: magento2, newsletter, magento2.3.3

In my website newsletter email is not sending. when subscribe I'm not getting an email but unsubscribe i'm getting an email 
can anyone please help me.

Thanks

Comment: You're using Mailchimp extension to send emails?

Comment: yes mailchimp and xtento smtp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using **MailChimp** extension in **Magento 2** then there is one system configuration in your Backend.

> Magento always manage emails : **Yes**

Please set above config value **No** and then save configuration and clear cache of Magento.

[image]

Otherwise only run below commands

```
php bin/magento config:set mailchimp/general/magentoemail 0
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Then it will work.

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Did you tried this ?

Comment: yes. it working

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer :) Happy to help you!

Comment: yes its working